# Why do I get a 400 status in this post command?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, rest, rest-assured

> When I run my rest-assure test againts my Spring Boot application with a RestController I get following error message:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
Expected status code <201> but was <400>
```

> My contoller look like this

```
package org.steinko.restapi;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@RestController
public class MessageController {
    
      @PostMapping("/message")
      public Message newMessage( @RequestBody Message aMessage) {
            return aMessage ; 
        }
      
      @GetMapping("/message")
      public Message getMessage( ) {
            return new Message("get message"); 
        }
      
}
```

> The Message Class look like this
> package org.steinko.restapi;

```
public class Message {
    
    private String message;
    
    public Message (String aMessage) {
        message = aMessage;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    

}
```

> The rest-assure API test looks like this

```
package tutorial;


import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;

public class MessageTest {
    
    @Test
    public void shouldStoreMessage() {
        
         
       String url =  "http://localhost:8080/message";   
       Message message = new Message("message");
       
       given()
         .contentType("application/json")
         .body(message)
       .when()
          .post(url)
       .then()
         .statusCode(201); 
    }
```

> How do I fix this error?

Comment: Is the `message` you add to the body in your test serialized? 400 is Bad Request so something is wrong there.

Comment: are you using correct port number? and it is not good idea to use same path value for both places. anyways just check port number.

Answer (score 1):

> Added

```
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.0'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.12.0'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.12.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
```

> to dependecies in gradle This fixed the error